# How to improve battery consumption of real time graphing?

Tags: android, plot, battery

I'm building an android application which draws a signal on a line plot for a real-time data output, showing 10 seconds in the past. drawSeries() is called in onDraw() and plots all of the series to the canvas. Is there any way I can improve battery life so it doesn't have to plot all datapoints each redraw?

```
private void drawSeries(Canvas canvas) {
    float x1Plot = getPxForDP(30);
    float y1Plot = getPxForDP(9);
    float x2Plot = getWidth() - getPxForDP(5);
    float y2Plot = getHeight() - getPxForDP(24);

    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    float dx = x2Plot - x1Plot;
    float dy = y2Plot - y1Plot;

    for (GraphSeries gs : series) {
        GraphPoint gpPrev = null;
        if (gs.dataList.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = gs.dataList.size() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
                GraphPoint gp = gs.dataList.get(i);
                if (gpPrev != null) {
                    if ((gpPrev.timestamp - now) / 1000 >= xMin) {
                        float x1 = x2Plot + (gpPrev.timestamp - now) / 1000F / (xMax - xMin) * dx;
                        float x2 = x2Plot + (gp.timestamp - now) / 1000F / (xMax - xMin) * dx;
                        float y1 = Math.min(Math.max(yMax - gpPrev.value, yMin), yMax) / (yMax - yMin) * dy + y1Plot;
                        float y2 = Math.min(Math.max(yMax - gp.value, yMin), yMax) / (yMax - yMin) * dy + y1Plot;
                        canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, gs.paint);
                    }
                }
                gpPrev = gp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm thinking of caching a bitmap of the lines and translating it, but I'm really not sure where to go with this.

Thanks for your time!